# how to check error in qunit

Tags: javascript, qunit, q

I have a function in JavaScript that uses the `q` library:

```
validateOnSelection : function(model) {
    this.context.service.doLofig(model).then(function(bResult) {
        if (bResult) {
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new Error(that.context.i18n.getText("i18n", "error"));
        }
    });
}
```

How can I check in qunit that the result is error? Let's assume that the result: `bResult` is `false` and `Error` should raise.

I tried:

```
test("Basic test ", {
    // get the oTemplate and model 

    return oTemplate.validateOnSelection(model).then(function(bResult) {
        // Now I need to check the error
    });

}));
```

The problem that I didn't get to the check "// Now I need to check the error"

Comment: Don't you need a function to use return statement? :)

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of things wrong there, I'm writing up an answer now...

Comment: @jakerella OK. I won't bother doing the same. :) Do not forget to mention `asyncTest, stop, start and throws` :)

Comment: Actually, `asyncTest` is deprecated as of 1.16.0. [Check it out](http://api.qunitjs.com/async/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of problems here. For one, you don't have any way to let the calling code know that your function has finished. Without that, QUnit can't determine when to run the assertions. Then you'll need to use QUnit's [async ability](http://api.qunitjs.com/category/async-control/), otherwise the test function finishes before your promise is resolved. Additionally, you can use the [`throws` assertion](http://api.qunitjs.com/throws/) to check for an error. The example below is using QUnit version 1.16.0 (the newest version).

```
validateOnSelection : function(model) {
    // Instead, return a promise from this method which your calling code can use:
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    this.context.service.doLofig(model).then(function(bResult) {
        if (bResult) {
            // return true; this doesn't really do anything, it doesn't return anywhere.
            // instead, resolve the promise:
            deferred.resolve(true);
        } else {
            // we don't really want to "throw" here, we nee to reject the promise:
            // throw new Error(that.context.i18n.getText("i18n", "error"));
            deferred.reject(new Error(that.context.i18n.getText("i18n", "error")));
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Now we can set up our test to wait for the promise to finish and then test the result...

```
QUnit.test("Basic test", function(assert) {
    // get the oTemplate and model 

    var done = QUnit.async(); // call this function when the promise is complete

    // where does `model` come from???
    oTemplate.validateOnSelection(model).then(function(bResult) {
        // Now I need to check the error
        assert.ok(bResult instanceof Error, "We should get an error in this case");

        done();  // now we let QUnit know that async actions are complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: How i can use with throws ?

Comment: The error is riase in validateSelection and I want to catch it in the qunit. I can't change the logic of validateSelection

Comment: You should not use `throws` given your setup. The `validateOnSelection()` method is asynchronous because of the promise, so you need to let QUnit know when things are finished. That will either need to happen through another promise (as I show you) or through a callback.

Comment: If you can't change that logic then there is no way to test this method if it is indeed asynchronous. You can't determine when the function will finish. QUnit will complete the test before your function returns.

Comment: why do I need to use q.defer ?

Comment: There are lots of options if you can change the `validateOnSelection()` method, but the point is that it is asynchronous and you have to let the calling code know when it is complete. I've used `Q.defer()` above so that we can return a promise from that method. The promise tells QUnit (or any other code) when the method is complete.